# The dependency StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core 2.4.0 does not support framework .NetStandard, Version=v1.6

Tags: azure, caching, .net-core, redis

We need search Azure Redis cache keys by using * to expire the desired keys. So we have tried to use StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core to achieve it.
We are facing for .netcore 1.0.1 and for 2.0
Also tried different versions of StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core like 1.0.0/2.1.0/2.2.0/2.3.0.2.4.0, but still getting same issue

For .net core 1.0.1, getting one more issue i.e “The dependency StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core 2.4.0 does not support framework .NetStandard, Version=v1.6”.

[image]

Comment: According to you mentioend screenshot that, it seems that tackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core is not supported you mentioned .net core framework.

Answer (score 0):

recently I've released the version 3 that include the support to .netstandard.

Please take a look and let me know